# Setting systemProperty in gradle.taskGraph.whenReady

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I am trying to read username and password needed to login to my application and assign it to a system property. I am able to read the values using `System.console().readLine` but I can't assign it to the system property. The property values are always null, I know its null as I did a `System.console().println` on the two properties.

The reason I am using `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady` is because I don't want password to be asked for every task but only when running the task meant for Live.

Below is my my code

```
def user_login =""
def pass_login =""

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    user_login = System.console().readLine("\nPlease enter username: ")
    pass_login = System.console().readPassword("\nPlease enter password: ")

    test {
        systemProperty "username", new String(user_login)
        systemProperty "password", new String(pass_login)    
    }
}
```

I have tried it without `test{...}` but that gives the below error message:

```
Could not find method systemProperty() for arguments [username,] on root project
```

I have searched a lot on google but did not find an answer to this issue, any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could just call `System.setProperty()`

I don't think there exists a method called `systemProperty` on either groovy or gradle

Edit:
Your application and the gradle script don't run in the same JVM instance. This means System properties set in the gradle script don't pass to the application. You'll need to find another way to get the user name and password in your application.

Comment: `System.setProperty("username", new String(user_login))`

Comment: Thanks @stav-saad  that seems to work within the gradle script, but it does not seem to be accessible in my test framework that passes the username/password to the application. I have used systemProperty within other tasks to set the username & password for environments where the username password is static and it works, but not from this block of code. Any ideas??

Comment: The test block is only available within tasks. It is not defined in the closure you used, therefore it does not work.

Comment: How did you print the property values? AFAIK, `System.console` cannot be used in a Gradle build script, at least not when running with the Gradle daemon. I don't think assigning is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the latest gradle docs, [Test](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:systemProperties) has a `systemProperties` property which takes a `Map`.  There is no `systemProperty`.  So, I believe you want the following (untested...see #2 below):

```
def user_login =""
def pass_login =""

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    user_login = System.console().readLine("\nPlease enter username: ")
    pass_login = System.console().readPassword("\nPlease enter password: ")

    test {
        systemProperties "username": user_login, "password": pass_login    
    }
}
```

I also wanted to add that I see a few issues with your approach that you may want to reconsider.

1. *gradle* is a build tool/platform and builds are intended to require the least amount of human intervention.  Shouldn't this be automated?  Entering your user name and password will grow very tiresome, very quickly.  I believe you should consider using [gradle properties](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties).  That way the build user sets their user name and password in their user `gradle.properties` file.  This has the added benefit of being available to multiple builds without the need to ever prompt the user.
2. Why is this happening in a `taskGraph` closure?  How does this depend on the `taskGraph` being setup?  How will other tasks in your build use this?  I don't believe that your code will work.  The `test` task, provided by whichever plugin you're using, has already been configured by the time the `taskGraph` is ready.  Google `gradle configuration vs execution` to get plenty of discussions on the topic, or use this [example](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/potential_traps.html#mkdirTrap).

Consider using:

```
/**
 * ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
 */
userName = me
userPassword = YouWillNeverKnow

/**
 * build.gradle
 */
apply plugin: 'java'
test {
        // use safe navigation to avoid missing property exception
        systemProperties "username": project?.userName, "password": project?.userPassword
    }
}
```

I tested the above, using my spock unit testing for my groovy project and it worked.

Comment: Using `systemProperties` also did not work for me, when I use `System.println("Username: "+ System.getProperty("username"))` outside of the `test{...}` block, it prints null on the console. I have used `systemProperty` in another named task `task(smokeOnLive, type: Test, dependsOn: ['clean'], description: "Run smoke tests", group: "Smoke")` like this `systemProperty "webdriver.type", System.getProperty("webdriver.type")` and it works, does not give any problem, its only when I try to use it in TaskGraph that I get the error message.

Comment: And to answer your questions, **1.** I use these scripts to run smoke tests on Live and on Release candidates and running on Live need our credentials to be entered, we cant store it anywhere, as per security policy. Its a small test suite, runs only for about 10 mins and is run every 2 weeks when we release software. **2.** I am doing this in TaskGraph because I want it to be asked only when the Smoke tests are run on Live and not when we run this on our Release candidate environments.